# Android home button listener

Tags: android, eclipse, audio, service

I'm currently developing an android app with eclipse. Basicaly when the home button is pressed, the app automaticaly call the onPause() method. In onPause() I put method to pause the background music. When the app is opened again, I'm want to put method to play the music but I don't know where to put it. Anyone know where to put method that we want to call 1st when the app is re-opened?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349685/not-able-disable-home-button-on-specific-android-devices. you cannot override the default behaviour of home button (as of android 4.0 i guess). This is for security reasons. Home button is one sure short way to navigate to home screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anyone know where to put method that we want to call 1st when the app is re-opened

You have to put it in the `onResume()` method.

Take a look at the Activity lifecycle:

[image]