# How to disable the hardware menu button in android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

How can i disable the hardware menu button in android wear programatically, So that I cannot navigate outside my appication?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable the *hard* Home button for an Android Smartphone or Android wear.

In general, it is bad design to disable or override the buttons that the user usually has a use for (e.g. For the Home button, getting back home to easily view and open other apps).

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10350208/4625829).